# how do I check for errors in the result object. Braintree

Tags: php

Am getting this after making my transaction

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property on Braintree\Result\Successful: message in C:\Users\kevin Muigai\Documents\My Web Sites\myWeb\best\best\braintree-php-3.34.0\lib\Braintree\Instance.php on line 35

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by upgrading to the latest braintree sdk